# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getAttribute')

Tags: javascript, typescript

Não consigo receber o valor da key específica para cada botão para à partir dela adicionar as quantidades e fazer a soma dos valores. Tentei colocar fora de um EventListener e o erro parou de acontecer, mas ainda assim no console apareciam todas as keys referentes a todos os botões.

```
var botaoAdicionar = document.querySelectorAll('.produto__botao');
    
    for (var i = 0; i < botaoAdicionar.length; i++) {
        botaoAdicionar[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
            let key = botaoAdicionar[i].getAttribute('key');
            console.log(key)
            listaLivros[key].quantidade++;
            atualizarCarrinho();
        })
    }
```

```
function atualizarCarrinho() {
    const containerCarrinho = document.querySelector('.carrinho__container');
    containerCarrinho.innerHTML = '';

    listaLivros.map((produto) => {
        if (produto.quantidade > 0) {
            containerCarrinho.innerHTML += `
            <article class="carrinho__produto">
                <img src="${produto.imagem}" alt="${produto.nome}" class="carrinho__produto__imagem">
                <div class="carrinho__produto__info">
                    <p class="carrinho__produto__titulo">${produto.nome}</p>
                    <div class="carrinho__produto__valores">
                        <p class="carrinho__produto__preco">R$ ${produto.valor},00</p>
                        <input type="number" class="carrinho__produto__quantidade" value="${produto.quantidade}">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>
            `
        }
    })
}
```

**Resolvi enviando o index como parâmetro da função. Obrigada.**

Answer (score -1):

Você deve capturar sua informação no evento despachado, da seguinte forma.

Mais informações em: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target

```js
var botaoAdicionar = document.querySelectorAll('.produto__botao');

for (var i = 0; i < botaoAdicionar.length; i++) {
  botaoAdicionar[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let key = e.target.getAttribute('key');
    console.log(key);
    //listaLivros[key].quantidade++;
    //atualizarCarrinho();
  })
}
```

```html
<button class="produto__botao" key="1">Key 1</button>
<button class="produto__botao" key="2">Key 2</button>
<button class="produto__botao" key="3">Key 3</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

Esse erro está acontecendo porque o seu `querySelector` não está encontrando nenhum elemento no `HTML`, logo o valor da `variável` `botaoAdicionar` é `null`.

Revise o seu `HTML` e veja se o elemento realmente existe ou se ele está sendo `renderizado` após a execução desse seu `JS`